# How do BB's work?

Tags: death-stranding

A Bridge Baby, or BB for short, allows one who connects to it to use it to see/detect BTs, Beached Things, in *Death Stranding*. It is a baby that lives in a pod filled with water that is usually attached on the chest and can be connected to by the wearer via a cord.

[image: Close up of Sam's Bridge Baby attached to his chest in its yellow pod; it is visible in there and Sam is connected to it via the cord at the moment]

But how do BBs work? How do they allow the wearer to see/detect BTs?

Comment: well they take 894 human souls to power

Answer (score 3):

As per the wiki article on [Bridge Babies](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Bridge_baby), it seems that their status of being both alive and dead (alive, and yet at the time of their delivery, still connected to their braindead mother), they serve as a bridge to the [World of the dead](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/World_of_the_dead) from whence BTs stem, allowing the bearer to experience the baby's perception of BTs in proxy through the artificial womb.

> A Bridge Baby is a seven months fetus removed via a cesarean section from a brain-dead mother. A stillmother's womb facilitates a connection between the world of the dead and a BB, granting the operatives the ability to sense and detect BTs when physically connected.

....

> Bridge Babies use a sensory mechanism similar to echolocation to detect BTs. The pod, designed to mimic the conditions inside a human womb, are key to preserving the BBs connections with this world and the other side. Bridge Babies are capable of producing something not unlike a dolphin's sound waves, travelling through the amniotic fluid and out the other side, bounce off BTs, and return as echoes, allowing a BB to ascertain the location of threats.

Comment: Bridge Baby sees big scary, terrifying thing and poops itself, not unlike the adults of the Death Stranding world.